# MySql Duplicated rows string comparation performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with more then 2 million records,
I need to find duplication records in column with string type additionaly I have index for this field.
I have next query:

```
select m.* from member as m
where lower(m.username) in 
(select lower(b.username) from member as b
where b.Username like 'a%'
group by b.username
having count(b.username) >= 2);
```

sub-query return only 4 records less then 0.2 seconds, but if I use them in where conditions section, this query working very long time and never return results....
I have tried to run next query, that theoretically the same logic:

> select * from member as m where lower(Username) in (lower('a1'),
>   lower('a2'),lower('a3'),lower('a4'));

and it works fine and fast.

what is the issues ? 
additionally I would like to run query with out  `where b.Username like 'a%'` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In common case MySQL can not use index for `IN` subqueries**

This is sad, but, actually, MySQL can not recognize "constant subqueries". What does it mean? It means that if you have a subquery that returns *static list of values* - and you use that in `IN` within another query, MySQL **will not** use index (by range).

**Why it is so?**

Actually, the most correct point is - because MySQL treats following queries:

```
.. WHERE `field` IN ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

and

```
.. WHERE `field` IN (SELECT `col` FROM t)
```

-as *different* queries (I'm assuming that column `col` in table `t` in second query have same values, i.e. `'foo', 'bar', 'baz'`). First query is equivalent for it's "expected" case, i.e. for *range of values*. But second query is equal for [= `ANY` subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) - and so MySQL will not use index for that.

**What to do**

Actually, your case and cases similar to it - are cases when it's better to split your query into two parts. First part will be retrieve *static list of values* from your table. Second part will substitute result of your first part into `IN` clause and then you'll get index using.

Alternative - you can use `JOIN` syntax for table to itself. That may seems useful if you want to resolve an issue with one query (or if your list is too long)

Comment: Thanks Alma Do, you mean what I need to write second query manually it is to many record in my case more them 500 values, it is not so useful.

Comment: Yes, it is. And for `500` values among `2.000.000` MySQL will use index without any doubt (if it have good cardinality, of course). So you'll have to select your items first in application, and then use them in second query. Alternatively, you can use `JOIN` syntax

Comment: Could you please share an example about JOIN for my case ?